# Can a fusion bomb make electricity?

Tags: electricity, power, fusion, explosions

Would blast energy remove a single piece of pre-cut earth above an underground explosive? Could you then break apart the piece of earth and lower it back into the cavity as a way of generating power? Could abundant fusion fuel be used cheaply to do this process with lasers or the bomb and get more energy out then was input?

Comment: Methinks "vaporize" or "pulverize" would be more appropriate than "break apart".

Comment: Something similar was tried with underground nuclear weapons, although the actual experiment was a fission only device if I remember correctly. The goal was to heat up a bunch of rock in the cave created by the blast and then pump water through it to heat the water and drive a generator or something like that. So yes, it could be possible, but people gave up on it. Too much radiation, maybe? Not efficient enough compared to conventional nuclear power?

Comment: I have a hard time believing you could make this anywhere near as efficient as a conventional nuclear reactor, so I don't see the point.

Comment: It's quite inappropriate to completely rewrite a question, even if it was closed.  It would invalidate every comment and the one answer made at a stroke.  You should ask a *new* question instead.

Answer (score 3):

> [Project PACER,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_PACER) carried out at Los Alamos National Laboratory (LANL) in the mid-1970s, explored the possibility of a fusion power system that would involve exploding small hydrogen bombs (fusion bombs)—or, as stated in a later proposal, fission bombs—inside an underground cavity. As an energy source, the system is the only fusion power system that could be demonstrated to work using existing technology. However it would also require a large, continuous supply of nuclear bombs, and contemporary economics studies demonstrated that these could not be produced at a competitive price compared to conventional energy sources.

So the answer is, it can , but it is not economically competitive

Comment: Huygens (allegedly) built an ice powered by gunpowder:  By 1682, the device had successfully shown that a dram (1/16th of an ounce) of gunpowder, in a cylinder seven or eight feet high and fifteen or eighteen inches in diameter, could raise seven or eight boys (or about 1,100 pounds) into the air. Experimental physics before ethics committees !